# My waterpik shower keeps running on pause

Tags: water

On my waterpik hand held shower, when i try to turn off the spray, the spray just reduces a little bit. It is supposed to just trickle. Any solutions?

Comment: Buy a new one maybe?  You could take it apart and fiddle with it to see if it can be adjusted or repaired...and then buy a new one I guess, after giving it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re head is flowing at a reduced rate the valve is likely defective. If it’s a trickle, this shower head is operating as designed. They’re not supposed to cut off supply 100% as per international plumbing code. This is to prevent scalding from unmixed hot water in the plumbing lines.

You’ll get used to it, enjoy!